# How to embed navigation portlet in a jsp in Liferay 7.1?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7.1

Is there a way to embed a navigation portlet in custom JSP? I know there is a way in theme to call the portlets but I don't think the same works in JSP.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sure.

You have a taglib to embedded a portlet within your custom jsp page, using the correct portlet name.

```
<liferay-portlet:runtime portletName="com_liferay_site_navigation_menu_web_portlet_SiteNavigationMenuPortlet">
</liferay-portlet:runtime>
```